# How to read _io.TextIOWrapper multiple times?

Tags: python, path, pathlib

I have the code below:

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> path = Path(r"C:\Users\slash\test.txt")
>>> f = path.open(encoding="utf-8")
>>> f
<_io.TextIOWrapper name="C:\\Users\\slash\\test.txt" mode='r' encoding='utf-8'>
>>> f.read()
'Test line 1\nTest line 2\nTest line 3\n'
>>> f.read()
''
```

Can you guys explain to me the behavior here - it looks like TextIOWrapper can only be read once?

Is there away to read it multiple times until I'm done?

Thank you.

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> path = Path(r"C:\Users\slash\test.txt")
>>> f = path.open(encoding="utf-8")
>>> f
<_io.TextIOWrapper name="C:\\Users\\slash\\test.txt" mode='r' encoding='utf-8'>
>>> f.read()
'Test line 1\nTest line 2\nTest line 3\n'
>>> f.read()
''
```

I'm expecting _io.TextIOWrapper can be read multiple times

Comment: f.[seek](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek)(0,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> f.read()
'Test line 1\nTest line 2\nTest line 3\n'
>>> f.read()
''
```

Imagine your `f` object is nothing but a **cursor**.
Once the cursor has ended readinig the file, you have to retake it to the beginning.

You can do this using the method [`seek`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) with arguments `(0, 0)`.

```
>>> f.read()
'Test line 1\nTest line 2\nTest line 3\n'
>>> f.seek(0,0)
>>> f.read()
'Test line 1\nTest line 2\nTest line 3\n'
```